# Typescript generics - how improve type inference for types by providing constructor

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I took look for questions suggested with search and with question form, but did not find a solution that suits my context.

Lately I have noticed, that Typescript can't detect type from provided constructor without repeating the type reference explicitly.
So, for function defined as:

```js
export interface IType<T> {
  new():T;
}

function useSomeType<T>(ctr:IType<T>, properties:Partial<T>);
```

I have to write something as:

```js
useSomeType<TypeName>(TypeName, {
  propName: 1
});
```

instead of

```js
useSomeType(TypeName, {
  propName: 1
 });
```

otherwise the IDE (webstorm) can't detect the `T` is `SomeType` for the `properties` parameter and can't offer intellicense and suggest properties names.

how I must define the type of these arguments for `useSomeType` to make intellisense of properties that `properties` have, like `propName` from example?

UPDATE:

I get this working on Typescript Playground:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuBhcVoG8CwAoa0AlgCYBc0yAToQHYDmA3HgUoQLbykAiYS8T+aByhg6nCkmr1oAXmgAieQIC+ePLT6UAZmGDxoASVgBPAA7wAPLAB8WZtBrwA7gAoAlKVgq1uPPAAepgD2lEhENJo6eoYA8gBGAFbwwEgQAGK6SCHGdoLAlPC8lrDQAXw0xDBBiclI1i5IZpxGTVbWADTQppRBphCkAApgoYRgIG0eXniqvrgg8GFRWZTGpAbxSSnpmdmyuQT5hXxWpf7lldDVm3UNTQBK8FprJuZtnd29-UMjYxOe+wRoPMwgUkP85I4nNBGuYHlp3AJAdBQQBXSg0aAbWoAOkgEEIdBoLlB7x6fTc0EgcER0BmMx8eCW2WxhyKLgQyDQeM6OEEwggonE8g5SHk0zcQA

```js
class TestClass {
  id: string;
  time:Date;
  message: string = "";
}

interface IType<T> {
  new():T;
}


export interface IObjectsFactory {
  create<T extends object>(type:IType<T>, props:Partial<T>):T;
}

let factory:IObjectsFactory = {
  create<T extends object>(typeRef:IType<T>, props:Partial<T>):T {
    let ret:T = new typeRef();
    return Object.assign(ret, props) as T;
  }
}



factory.create(TestClass, {
  message: "Test"
// the properties are listed by playground
});
```

PROBLEM

this does not work for me if these are different files (and packages), like:

- `IType<T>` is defined in one package referenced - `@sakartvelosoft/types-metadata` to be precise.
- the interfaces declared in one file, the implementation - in another, the tests - in third.
  All this inside package within monorepo.

My declarations:

```js
import {CallableIdFactory} from "@sakartvelosoft/id-generation";
import {IType} from "@sakartvelosoft/types-metadata";



export interface EventMetadata {
    type: string;
    id: string;
    timestamp: Date;
    source:string;
    targets?: string[];

    scopeOrModuleId?: string;

    preferredChannel?:string;

}

export interface EventDetails<T> extends EventMetadata {
    data: T;
}

export interface EventCreationOptions {
    source?: string;
    targets?:string[];

    scopeOrModuleId?: string;

    preferredChannel?:string;
}

export interface IEventsFactoryOptions {
    eventIdFactory?:CallableIdFactory;
    source?:string;
    targets?:string[];
    targetsCleanup?:(eventType: string, source:string, targets:string[]) => string[];
}

export interface IEventFactoryEntry<T extends object> {
    createEvent(data:Partial<T>, options?:EventCreationOptions):EventDetails<T>;
    rebuildEvent(eventMetadata:EventMetadata, data:object):EventDetails<T>;
}
export interface IEventsFactory {
    registerEventsType<T extends object>(eventType:IType<T>, typeAlias?:string):void;
    forEvent<T extends object>(eventType: IType<T>):IEventFactoryEntry<T>;
    forEventByAlias<T extends object>(eventTypeAlias:string):IEventFactoryEntry<T>;

    createEvent<T>(typeDef:IType<T>, data:Partial<T>, options?:EventCreationOptions):EventDetails<T>;
    rebuildEvent(eventMetadata:EventMetadata, data:object):EventDetails<T>;

}
```

The tests:

```js
import {describe} from "mocha";
import {createEventsFactory} from "../src";
import {createTypesRegistry} from "@sakartvelosoft/types-metadata";
import {expect} from "chai";

describe('Test events construction and rebuilding', () => {
    class TestEvent {
        message: string;
    }
    it('Construct event', () => {
        const eventFactory = createEventsFactory(createTypesRegistry(), { source: 'test' });
        eventFactory.registerEventsType(TestEvent, 'test-event');
        const newEvent = eventFactory.createEvent(TestEvent,  {
            message: "Demo"

        });
        expect(newEvent.data).haveOwnProperty('test');
        expect(newEvent.data).instanceof(TestEvent);
        expect(newEvent.data.test).eql('Demo');
    })
})
```

UPDATE 2:

The (almost) mentioned code seems to works at TSFiddle as expected (properties of TestEvent are recognized/understood/listed), but not in WebStorm project, if I understand this correctly, and this is very strange that Webstorm can't inferm types propertly while TSFiddle can.

TSFiddle link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/tsfiddle-quxumi?file=src%2Fapp%2Finterfaces.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ftest-code.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fstubs.ts

UPDATE 3

As the TSFiddle does not have the explicit `tsconfig.json` file, as I see, and they are use some built-in "configuration", I provide the `tsconfig` at root of my project where I experience this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "target": "ES2021",
    "lib": ["ES2021"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "declaration": true
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*.ts", "./tests/**/*.ts"],
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

the `.eslintrc.js`:

```js
/* eslint-env node */
module.exports = {
  extends: ['eslint:recommended', 'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended'],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
  root: true,
};
```

dev-dependencies list from `package.json`:

```json
{
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.3.5",
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^18.16.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.2",
    "chai": "^4.3.7",
    "eslint": "^8.39.0",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "ts-mocha": "^10.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  }
}
```

WORKAROUND

After working further on problem cause and impacting configuration and issues, I found that downgrading from TypeScript version like latest `5.0.2` to older one, like `4.8.4` seems to fix the problem. Still, hope it will be fixed with `5.0.2` typescript versions, I added a related bug at their (Webstorm) tracker.

Will close the issue as workaround is available.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] where we can see what you're seeing if we paste the code into our own IDEs.  Right now it looks like pseudocode and missing declarations, so I'm not prepared to proceed.

Comment: Seems an extract of your code please provide the full code.

Comment: @jcalz updated with more detailed examples.

Comment: @jmvcollaborator Updated the question with detailed example. Actually problem happens in more complicated setting, than 1 file of Typescript playground.

Comment: cant run playground :)

Comment: @jmvcollaborator for that case I pasted the full playground text below the link.  If same tactic that works in playground worked in project, with code across packages and files, then I would not ask that question...

Comment: If the only way to reproduce this is to set up a project locally then you might not get the amount of engagement you want here.  If nobody responds, could you try to make a multi-file project in a web IDE other than the TS Playground and link to that in the question?

Comment: @jcalz I added a TSFiddle  link but as I can understand, then it seems an online fiddle app better understands the code than WebStorm?! It is very strange at least. Westomem gives me false errors about invalid property names and uses `unknown` for generic parameters instead of type that should be inferable from provided constructor

Comment: I suspect it is because of the tsconfig. Can you try to put your tsconfig to tsfiddle or reverse, to see whether error appears/dissapears

Comment: @wonderflame added tsconfig to the tsfiddle but I suspect it does not have any impact on the situation, either because it implemented in a way it ignore provided `tsconfig.json` or because it does not the cause of problems this issue is about.

Answer (score 0):

WORKAROUND

After working further on problem cause and impacting configuration and issues, I found that downgrading from TypeScript version like latest `5.0.2` to older one, like `4.8.4` seems to fix the problem. Still, hope it will be fixed with 5.0.2 typescript versions, I added a related bug at their (Webstorm) tracker.

Will close the issue as workaround is available.